# What did I do wrong with this Loop video playback (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript

Look at this code. I think I am almost done but there is a minor problem.

```html
<html>
<head>

<script>
var sentences= 
[
 ['journey27.mp4', 
  [
    [1, 2],
    [5, 7]
  ]
 ],
 ['journey28.mp4', 
  [
    [10, 12],
    [13, 17],
    [25, 36]
  ]
 ],
 ['journey29.mp4', 
  [
    [13, 15],
    [15, 19],
    [21, 30]
  ]
 ]
];

let video_index = 0;
let time_index = 0;
let repeat = 0;



function playVideo(myUrl, startTime, endTime) { 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=myUrl + " start:"+startTime+" end: "+endTime+"<br>";
  var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  video.src = 'video/'+myUrl;
  video.currentTime=startTime;
  video.play();

  var maxTime = endTime;
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if(video.currentTime >= maxTime){
     myLoop();
     
    }
  }, false);

} 


function myLoop(){
  playVideo(sentences[video_index][0], sentences[video_index][1][time_index][0], sentences[video_index][1][time_index][1]);
  repeat++;
  if (repeat >= 3) {
    repeat = 0;
    time_index++;
    if (time_index >= sentences[video_index][1].length) {
      time_index = 0;
      video_index++;
    }
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>


<video id="myVideo" width="500" height="400" controls autoplay loop>

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<br>
<a href="#" onclick="myLoop()" > Play </a>

<br>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the requirement

I want to build an video app (using Javascript) that repeats each segment of a video **3 times** before moving to the next segment.

There are **many videos** and each video has **many segments**.

The urllinks and segments are provided or pulled from database. They are constructed in a nested array.

When I click "**play**" **once**, the app should **do all the following things**:

The app should play the video "**journey27.mp4**", from second 1 to 2, 3 times. That means it should play from second 1 to 2 then when the second is > than 2, it gets back and start from second 1 again and then when the second is > than 2, it gets back and start from second 1 again and then when the second is > than 2, **it jump to the next** segment of video "**journey27.mp4**". That means it will do this

it plays "**journey27.mp4**" from 5 to 7, then
it plays "**journey27.mp4**" from 5 to 7, then
it plays "**journey27.mp4**" from 5 to 7, then it jumps to the next video

it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 10 to 12, then
it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 10 to 12, then
it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 10 to 12, then it jumps to the next segment of the video "**journey28.mp4**" and

it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 13 to 17, then
it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 13 to 17, then
it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 13 to 17, then it jumps to the next segment of the video "**journey28.mp4**" and

it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 25 to 36, then
it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 25 to 36, then   
it plays "**journey28.mp4**" from 25 to 36, then it jumps to the next video

it plays "**journey29.mp4**" from 13 to 15, then     
it plays "**journey29.mp4**" from 13 to 15, then     
it plays "**journey29.mp4**" from 13 to 15, then it jumps to the next segment of "**journey29.mp4**"

and so on.

When playing this code, it plays the first segment correctly

it plays "**journey27.mp4**" from 1 to 2, then
it plays "**journey27.mp4**" from 1 to 2, then
it plays "**journey27.mp4**" from 1 to 2,

However, it doesn't repeat the second segment

**What is wrong with it?**

I think I need a few lines of code to fix it.

Comment: Do you have a functional example?

Comment: @Ouroborus, you can copy the code and run on your PC. The whole html file is in the question

Comment: Or you could provide a functional example.

Comment: @Ouroborus, I am a newbee, I don't know how to do that

Comment: When you're editing, there's a button that looks sort of like a square with `<>` in it. It'll let you create a run-able snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **wrong** is adding an event listener callback for `timeupdate` on each loop, so all those callbacks will run simultaneously and will conflict with each other. After fixing that, your code seems to work as expected:

```html
<html>
<head>

<script>
var sentences= 
[
 [//'journey27.mp4', 
 'https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4',
  [
    [1, 2],
    [5, 7]
  ]
 ],
 [//'journey28.mp4', 
 'https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
  [
    [10, 12],
    [13, 17],
    [25, 36]
  ]
 ],
 [//'journey29.mp4', 
 'https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/WeAreGoingOnBullrun.mp4',
  [
    [13, 15],
    [15, 19],
    [21, 30]
  ]
 ]
];

let video_index = 0;
let time_index = 0;
let repeat = 0;

var video;
var maxTime;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  video = document.getElementById("myVideo");

  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if(video.currentTime >= maxTime){
      myLoop();
    }
  }, false);
});

function playVideo(myUrl, startTime, endTime) { 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=myUrl + " start:"+startTime+" end: "+endTime+"<br>";
  
  // video.src = 'video/'+myUrl;
  video.src = myUrl;
  video.currentTime=startTime;
  video.play();
  maxTime = endTime;
} 


function myLoop(){
  if (!sentences[video_index]) {
    video.src = null;
    return;
  }
  playVideo(sentences[video_index][0], sentences[video_index][1][time_index][0], sentences[video_index][1][time_index][1]);
  repeat++;
  if (repeat >= 3) {
    repeat = 0;
    time_index++;
    if (time_index >= sentences[video_index][1].length) {
      time_index = 0;
      video_index++;
    }
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>


<video id="myVideo" width="500" height="400" controls autoplay loop>

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<br>
<a href="#" onclick="myLoop()" > Play </a>

<br>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```